# Using int variable to plot between x axis dateTime chart?

Tags: c#, datetime, for-loop, charts, datetimepicker

Im new to window forms so forgive me if this seems a little trivial. I have a graph that takes two times from the user, a start and end time. I wish to plot this on a graph but for the graph to also show the period inbetween as a bar chart. So start time indicates the first bar plot, the barchart will remain at the same y coordinate until it reaches the end time.

Obviously I have have tried int j; but had a thought of using j as a DateTime variable to see if that worked but no luck.

This is my code so far:

```
` 
 private void Create_Graph()
    {
        double kwh = double.Parse(textBox13.Text);
        DateTime t1 = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime j = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0); ///Variable for between times


        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dateTimePicker1.Value, kwh);
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dateTimePicker2.Value, kwh);

        if ((j >= dateTimePicker1.Value) && (j < dateTimePicker2.Value))
        {
            j = j.AddMinutes(15);

            for (i = 0; i < 96; i++)
            {
                timeSlots[i] = t1;
                t1 = t1.AddMinutes(15);
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeSlots[i], kwh);                   
            }
        }

        chart1.Series[0].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        chart1.Series[0]["PixelPointWidth"] = "4";
        chart1.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "1";


    }`
```

and this was my initial try with int j;

```
'
 private void Create_Graph()
    {
        double kwh = double.Parse(textBox13.Text);
        DateTime t1 = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
        int j:
        j = 0;

        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dateTimePicker1.Value, kwh);
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dateTimePicker2.Value, kwh);

        if ((j >= dateTimePicker1.Value) && (j < dateTimePicker2.Value)) j++;
        {


            for (i = 0; i < 96; i++)
            {
                timeSlots[i] = t1;
                t1 = t1.AddMinutes(15);
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(timeSlots[i], kwh);                   
            }
        }

        chart1.Series[0].ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        chart1.Series[0]["PixelPointWidth"] = "4";
        chart1.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "1";


    }
```

Comment: Your choice of variable names makes your code extremely hard to read. Please correct it.

Comment: The magic number 96 denotes what?  I could presume 96 15 minute intervals in one day.  But then why do we need both a start date and end date if we only display one day?

Comment: Hi @Steve yes exactly my graph has 1 hour intervals with 15minute ones between them, it was just that when i chose int j to be a variable between the times it was just a thought i had by trying to change to a datetime variable